# Understanding a chart about likelihood

Tags: statistics

I am learning stats from *All of Statistics 1e*. I understand that likelihood is the probability of a parameter, given some data. So if you flip an unknown coin 1000 times and get 500 heads a parameter p(heads) = .5 has a higher likelihood than p(heads) = .1.

That said, I am having trouble understanding the following chart from page 125, which the book says is a likelihood function for Uniform(0, $\theta$) for when $\theta$ = .75. The vertical lines show the observed data.

What is the meaning of the staircase-like black line? I understand why this line might drop to zero if x > .75 (because these would be outside the range of possible values if $\theta$ = .75. But how does it jump higher than 1 between 0 and .75 along the x-axis? Can someone explain what is happening in the picture?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the stair step line is the PDF for a uniform(0, 0.75) distribution.  The area under this line must be 1.0 so the height of the line should be 4/3, since 4/3 x 0.75 = 1.

Then, you are showing a set of observed values sampled from your population, where it appears the range of values goes beyond the support of this particular distribution function (your data values extend beyond 0.75).  From this you might conclude that 0.75 is not perhaps the best estimate for theta.

Comment: so the stair line is the pdf and not the likelihood function. that would make sense then. I know the likelihood function does not necessarily integrate to 1.